# How to eval string/convert string to Expr

Tags: julia

Is there a method to convert a string to Expr? I tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
julia> convert(Expr, "a=2")
ERROR: MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type String to an object of type Expr
This may have arisen from a call to the constructor Expr(...),
since type constructors fall back to convert methods.

julia> Expr("a=2")
ERROR: TypeError: Expr: expected Symbol, got String
 in Expr(::Any) at ./boot.jl:279
```

Comment: I think you want `parse("a=2")` (it will convert to `Symbol` or `Expr` depending on the contents of the string)

Comment: Thank you. It's what I need. I skimmed the docs (http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.5/manual/metaprogramming/) at the middle for Expr but missed to check that ```parse``` is right at the top section of the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Colin said, to convert to `Expr` (or `Symbol`) you use `parse`.
And then to evaluate the resulting `Expr` you use `eval`.
Both together:

```
julia> eval(parse("a = 2"))
2
```

Answer (score 11):

`parse` doesn't work here anymore. Now you need `Meta.parse`:

```
eval(Meta.parse("a = 2"))
```

(As pointed out by Markus Hauschel in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41276304/how-to-eval-string-convert-string-to-expr#comment102002456_53230001).)

Comment: Finally a useful one :)

Answer (score 0):

Note that as of Julia 1.0, this no longer works. Generally if you want to be evaluating string expression in Julia 1.0 you should be using expressions all the way through, e.g. `:(a=2)`

```
julia> parse("a=2")
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching parse(::Expr)

julia> @show eval(:(a=2))
eval($(Expr(:quote, :(a = 2)))) = 2
2
```

Comment: Please share your code when answering a question with the output so people can reproduce it.

Comment: what about `eval(Meta.parse("a = 2"))` ?

Comment: The reply of @MarkusHauschel should be the accepted answer. It worked, thanks!